# windows hpc run on Ansys fluent

Tags: windows, fluent, hpc

I use the parrallel caculation of Fluent by Windows hpc.But when I enter the Fluent and software is no response all the time. How can i adjust the options then I can use normally. thank you for your answer!
The details:1.I have set the shared folder already.2.And every HPC node is normal connection.3.I have setup the msmpi already.4.All the computers use same account and password.
Fllow the ANSYS help. I have meet all conditions already.But when I run the  parrallel caculation the Fluent prompt ABORTING Access denied by node HPC002.